# Jekyll site html form which submits to a different page but redirects to another

Tags: javascript, html, forms, jekyll, static-site

I have a Jekyll site and a contact page on which I made a simple form and connected it with service like FormSpree or SimpleForm which automatically sends the responses to my inbox, what I would like to do is redirect to a Thank you for your response page after the form is submitted. Attempted this in many ways like adding event listener to the submit button or using `onSubmit` or `action` properties of the form but I was only able to achieve one of the two things, either the form submits or I am redirected to the Thank You Page, unable to perform both when I have no access to the server side script which I could have used for redirection. The form is pretty basic, a few input fields and a submit button. Would appreciate any form of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both services allow a hidden field, in your form, which points to the thank you URL you want to be redirected after submission.

with FormSpree use `_next` (*see [advanced features](https://formspree.io/)*)

```
<input type="hidden" name="_next" value="https://my-site.tld/thanks.html" />
```

with SimpleForm use `redirect_to` (*see the [sample code](https://getsimpleform.com/) in their page*)

```
<input type='hidden' name='redirect_to' value='https://my-site.tld/thanks.html' />
```